# Trigger function inside observer only on new data, not on activity recreation

Tags: android, kotlin

I have this observer inside an activity and I want to make part of it run only when we have new data and not when the activity is recreated (like when you rotate screen)

```
signInViewModel.signInResponse.observe(this, {
                response->  when(response){
            is NetworkResult.Success ->{
                response.data?.let {
                    signInViewModel.saveJwt(it)
                   
                }
            }

            is NetworkResult.Error ->{
                errorMsg.text = response.message.toString()
                
            }

            is NetworkResult.Loading -> {

            }
        }
        })
```

I want to run this **`signInViewModel.saveJwt(it)`** only when we get new data and other part run when we get new data and when we recreate the activity.

Comment: response.data->what type  it is?

Comment: It doesn't make sense for the Activity to be involved in this. If the ViewModel wants to call this function when it receives a new value, why doesn't it do it internally? It's convoluted to have the Activity reach into the ViewModel and tell it how to do its job.

Comment: @Tenfour04 so you are saying that I should manage that inside the ViewModel ?

Comment: Yes, I don't know why you wouldn't. The activity is just a view. It shouldn't care about details like that, so it shouldn't be involved.

Comment: @Tenfour04 one thing that prevented me from doing that is that: after saving the token I have to start another activity (with intent) should that be done in in ViewModel too ?

Comment: ViewModel should not be aware that such a thing as a view or an Activity exists. It just presents data and accepts commands. I would save the data internally in the ViewModel and then publish the value in a LiveData as ready for consumption. The Activity can decide what to do then and not worry about saving it.

Comment: @Tenfour04 what I was talking is that if there is any way to check inside the observer which is the source (in case is new data or recreation of activity) as if I startActivity(intent) inside the observer, when I come back to it it still executes that and it is some kind of loop

Comment: Maybe split your NetworkResult.Success class into two classes or give it a boolean so you can distinctly represent *just logged in* state. Expose a function in the ViewModel that lets you consume the state, which causes it to emit a Success state that is *not* just logged in. The Activity can call this function when it first starts the other Activity. This idea is conflating network response and UI state a bit. I think it could use some more thought to make it cleaner separation of concerns, but maybe it's a start.

Answer (score 1):

override onChange method, that should only run when the data changes.

By far this should solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, you want to observe your `NetworkResult` only once when it's in (Success) state, and multiple times for other status as your replay for **@Gouse Mohiddin** answer. I'll recommend for your same **@Gouse Mohiddin** answer to use `StateFlow` with some different changes...

First of all you need to create some method in your ViewModel to reset your stateFlow to your default.

**ViewModel**

```
private val _signInResponse = MutableStateFlow<NetworkResult(NetworkResult.Loading)
val signInResponse : StateFlow<NetworkResult> = _signInResponse.asStateFlow()

fun resetSignInResponse(){
    _signInResponse.value = _signInResponse.value.copy(NetworkResult.Default)
}
```

When you receive your new data use same

```
_signInResponse.value = _signInResponse.value.copy(NetworkResult.Success(jwt))
```

**Activity**

```
signInViewModel.signInResponse.collect { response ->
        when (response) {
            is NetworkResult.Success -> {
                response.data?.let {
                    signInViewModel.saveJwt(it)
                    //After receiving success data, reset your state to default 
                    //this will never run again unless you receive new data
                    signInViewModel.resetSignInResponse()
                }
            }

            is NetworkResult.Error -> {
                //this will run always if you hold an error in state
                errorMsg.text = response.message.toString()
            }

            is NetworkResult.Default -> {
                //Ignore Or Apply the default actions you want
            }
        }
    }
```

and don't forget to reset your state to default before any updates (emits).

```
resetSignInResponse()
```

Comment: This approach looks like a correct one, I will try that later on and come back to mark it as accepted if this is the one.

Comment: Okay, good luck 

Answer (score 0):

You should use Kotlin StateFlow instead of liveData

StateFlow will emit new data only (not any duplicate)

Only change required is

```
private val _signInResponse = MutableStateFlow<NetworkResult>(NetworkResult.Loading)
val signInResponse : StateFlow<NetworkResult> = _signInResponse
```

When you have the data simply call

```
_signInResponse.value = NetworkResult.Success(jwt)
```

And Handle like this

```
signInViewModel.signInResponse.collect{ response->  

        when(response){

        is NetworkResult.Success ->{
            response.data?.let {
                signInViewModel.saveJwt(it)
               
            }
        }

        is NetworkResult.Error ->{
            errorMsg.text = response.message.toString()
            
        }

        is NetworkResult.Loading -> {

        }
    }
    }
```

Comment: but it will not run the errorMsg.text = response.message.toString() when the activity is recreated as this part I want to run on new data and when the activity is recreated, the success part is the one that should only run when new data is emitted